# Is it possible to set width & height by class in <use> tag?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, width

I need to set icon size using testSvgIcons class in use tag somehow. I know that it's available to use width and height attributes, but I need class (or sth else).

```css
    .testSvgIcons {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        fill: green;
    }
```

```html
<svg style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="tick-icon" viewBox="0 0 515.556 515.556">
        <path d="m0 274.226 176.549 176.886 339.007-338.672-48.67-47.997-290.337 290-128.553-128.552z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<svg>
    <use href="#tick-icon" class="testSvgIcons"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just removed the class from use and added to parent SVG

```css
.testSvgIcons {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="tick-icon" viewBox="0 0 515.556 515.556">
        <path d="m0 274.226 176.549 176.886 339.007-338.672-48.67-47.997-290.337 290-128.553-128.552z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="testSvgIcons">
    <use href="#tick-icon" ></use>
</svg>
```